# How to make auto casting between list item?

Tags: c#

I define 2 object:

```
   public sealed class obj1
   {
       public int i1;
       public string str1
   }

   public sealed class obj2
   {
      public int i2;
      public string str2

   public static explicit operator obj2( obj1 e )
   {
       return new obj2()
       {

           i2   = e.i1;
           str2 = e.str; 

       }
   }
```

}

Now, i define 2 list that contain object

```
List<obj1> obj1item;
List<obj2> obj2item = new List<obj2>();

obj2item.add(o1);
obj2item.add(o2);
```

And now, I want to add the object from `obj2item` to `obj1item`;

That mean that i want to do

```
 obj1Item = obj2Item
```

I used the linq to do it

```
    var v = from t in obj2item
            select (obj1) t;

    foreach (var item in v)
    {
        obj1item.Add(item);
    }
```

***My question:***

Is there some other way to do add the obj2Item items to obj1Item ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
obj1item.AddRange(v.Cast<obj1>())
```

Comment: and if the collection that i using is not a list => if the collection is ObservableCollection and i dont have the method 'AddRange'

Comment: Then you can still use a 'foreach'-loop and use the 'Add'-method